# How to safely sanitize input from TinyMCE in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, youtube, xss

I just added TinyMCE to a small CMS I built in Rails. I've been using Redcloth before to style user generated articles.

Since I started using TinyMCE, I would like to also allow users to embed video (from youtube for ex) into their blog posts.

I'm using the follow helper in the views:

```
sanitize(text,
        :tags => %w(a object p param h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 br hr ul li img),
        :attributes => %w(href name src type value width height data) )
```

Is this safe? Or should I not allow those tags? If so, which tags can I allow? How can I test to make sure?

This is still in staging.

Thanks

Deb

Comment: You're pretty much getting rid of any stylings all together with that. Why use TinyMCE ?

Comment: They can add images, lists, headers and videos. No one wants to use textile except me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to use all tags you want using the [valid_elements configuration option](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements), check out the default setting you can expand. You may also have a look at the [custom_elements option.](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#custom_elements)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the issue of TinyMCE not allowing YouTube embeds in Rails, or stripping out the iFrame embed code - this worked for me in Rails 7, Jan. 2023:

```
<%= sanitize @post.body, tags: %w( iframe ), attributes: %w(width height src source) %>
```